# how to control on the position of toolbar Item in SWT?

Tags: java, swt

I have 3 ToolItem  : text , item1 , item2

I want that text item will be align to the left and item 1 and item 2 will be align to the right

for example

```
 text                         item1,item2
```

This is the code

ToolBar treeToolBar = new ToolBar(treeComposite, SWT.NONE);

```
    filterText = new Text(treeToolBar, SWT.BORDER);

    ToolItem textItem = new ToolItem(treeToolBar, SWT.SEPARATOR);
    textItem.setControl(filterText);
    textItem.setWidth(filterText.computeSize(SWT.DEFAULT, SWT.DEFAULT, true).x);

    Item1 = new ToolItem(treeToolBar, SWT.PUSH | SWT.RIGHT);

    item2 = new ToolItem(treeToolBar, SWT.PUSH | SWT.RIGHT);
```

Comment: if you want to have the items on the right side, you can create the toolbar with SWT.RIGHT_TO_LEFT bit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want item1 and item2 somewhere in the middle, add a new item with style `SWT.SEPARATOR` and set the desired width to offset the two items.

If you really want the two items to be at the right side of the toolbar, you have to compute dynamically the size of that separator. Basically you subtract from the size of the toolbar the size of the three items (one text and two push items).

Here is a complete snippet where the text is aligned to the left and the buttons to the right. The `toolbar.pack()` call is necessary to compute also the space used between the items and the trimming. We have to take that also into account.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final Display display = new Display();
    final Shell shell = new Shell(display);
    shell.setLayout(new FillLayout());

    final Composite treeComposite = new Composite(shell, SWT.NONE);
    treeComposite.setLayout(new GridLayout());

    final ToolBar treeToolBar = new ToolBar(treeComposite, SWT.NONE);
    treeToolBar.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, false));

    final Text filterText = new Text(treeToolBar, SWT.BORDER);

    final ToolItem textItem = new ToolItem(treeToolBar, SWT.SEPARATOR);
    textItem.setControl(filterText);
    textItem.setWidth(filterText.computeSize(SWT.DEFAULT, SWT.DEFAULT, true).x);

    final ToolItem separator = new ToolItem(treeToolBar, SWT.SEPARATOR);
    separator.setWidth(0);

    final ToolItem item1 = new ToolItem(treeToolBar, SWT.PUSH | SWT.RIGHT);
    item1.setImage(display.getSystemImage(SWT.ICON_WORKING));

    final ToolItem item2 = new ToolItem(treeToolBar, SWT.PUSH | SWT.RIGHT);
    item2.setImage(display.getSystemImage(SWT.ICON_QUESTION));

    treeToolBar.pack();
    final int trimSize = treeToolBar.getSize().x - textItem.getWidth() - item1.getWidth() - item2.getWidth();

    treeToolBar.addListener(SWT.Resize, new Listener() {
        @Override
        public void handleEvent(Event event) {
            final int toolbarWidth = treeToolBar.getSize().x;
            final int itemsWidth = textItem.getWidth() + item1.getWidth() + item2.getWidth();
            final int separatorWidth = toolbarWidth - itemsWidth - trimSize;
            separator.setWidth(separatorWidth);
        }
    });

    shell.open();
    while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
            display.sleep();
        }
    }
    display.dispose();
}
```

[image]

Comment: reeToolBar.getSize().x = 0 in my case also can i do the event not on the shell but for the treeComposite in my case the ToolBar treeToolBar = new ToolBar(treeComposite, SWT.NONE); and not from the shell

Comment: @user1365697 that's because the items have no text and no images. Move the mouse to the right of the text, just left to the shell border and they will appear. Or you could set some text or icons to the items. I wanted to keep the snippet minimal.

Comment: @user1365697 you can put the listener on the `ToolBar` itself. All you have to remember is to compute and save the space used for trimms. That is why I called `pack()`: to get the size of the tool bar with text, buttons and trims.

Comment: I need to do it dynamically

Comment: is it ok that the trimSize = -122 ?

Comment: what should be the event of ToolBar in this case ?

Comment: @user1365697 I changed my snippet to match more closely your code and attached a screenshot. If by dynamically you mean that you keep adding items, you have to recompute the trim size after each change: set size of separator to 0, pack, save trim, and then apply new difference again to the separator.

Comment: I added in my answer a new `Resize` listener. Check this line: `treeToolBar.addListener(SWT.Resize, new Listener() {`. Just copy in you code the lines where I create the separator (including setting size 0), the pack, the declaration and initialization of variable trimSize and the code where I add the listener to the toolbar.